# Error:Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Trying to implement GCM notifications, got the conflict error

**   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.

> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 8.3.0.**

```
dependencies {
compile project(':viewPagerIndicator')
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.4'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.+'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'
//classpath 'com.splunk:mint-gradle-android-plugin:5.1.0'
//  compile 'com.splunk:mint-android-sdk:5.1.0'
//compile 'com.splunk:mint-android-instrumentation-okhttp:5.1.0'
compile 'com.splunk.mint:mint:5.0.0'

           }
   apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Here is my Application Gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
 maven{
url "https://mint.splunk.com/gradle/"
 }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha6'

}
}
```

Comment: Please help me what i can do?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the **v.9.4.0** you have to use the v.3.0.0 of the google play services plugin:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
```

Comment: How do you know which version of gms needs what version of the google play services plugin? Specifically, how did you link version 9.4.0 with v3.0.0 of the google play services plugin?

Comment: @TonyChan All info here. https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin

Comment: I've read that page and don't see a list of minimum requirements. I was imagining a table or something relating specific versions of gms to specific versions of the plugin. Even the release notes don't mention when new plugin versions are required.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a more explanatory error log in your logcat. It appears before this error message `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices` which you reported.
Please post the complete error log message.

Also, I see that you have two dependencies for gradle in your application gradle; this `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'` and this `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha6'` . I suggest to keep only `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'` and ALSO **add `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1'` in this gradle.**

Check your cradle-wrapper.properties to contain `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.8-all.zip` or `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip` instead of those alpha releases.

If the problem still remains, please post the complete error message (preferably the whole log in your logcat) plus build-tools, targetsdk and compileSdk version of your module gradle file.